# Experience Bundle Metadata - how to retrieve an API Name of the Page?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, experience-cloud

I created a new Page in my Customer Experience site, called 'Test Page'. Its properties are shown in the following image:

[image]

I would like to retrieve its API Name, in this case it's `Test_Page__c`. I retrieved the [Experience Bundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) metadata but could not find a reference to such value in any of files.

Is there any other way to retrieve it or when referencing to Experience page's name I am always forced to get through SF's Setup?

Comment: There is a known issue that [Experience Pages change their API Name upon deployment via Experience Bundle](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002ieQpQAI&title=experience-pages-change-their-api-name-upon-deployment). Also see [The API Name for page/routes is not respected when deploying ExperienceBundle metadata between orgs](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000024G3OQAU)